# GET page in url getting doubled cause of htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get, subdirectory

So I'm trying to hide my sub folder using htaccess. It does its job, but some GET page gets error.

so instead of getting this

```
hello.com/tentang_kami?page=visi
```

I'm getting this (It happens after I add the function to hide subfolder in htaccess)

```
hello.com/tentang_kami?page=visi?page=visi
```

here is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /$1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(html|php)[\s?/] [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /%1%2 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+halaman/+visitor([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^halaman/visitor/)^(.*)$ /halaman/visitor/$1 [L,NC]
```

I'm pretty new to hosting a web. If anyone could provide any help that would be great.